# Error: usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: errors, mac

Recently I'm getting an error on my macbook air since i've upgraded to Yosemite:

> usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Anybody who knows how I can solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the error message?

Comment: I'm using currently TexMaker, but for some reason he won't quick build my .tex file. This is the error when I'm trying build it: usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: Does this occur with any `.tex` file? (I can't test anyway, since I am not using Mac)

Comment: There is an extra `"` that should not belong there, at the end of `pdflatex`. Check if your compilation command in TexMaker has this as well. If it does, remove it.

Comment: This is actually the full error, my apologies:

Error : could not start the command : "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "assignment_3".tex

Comment: Ok, i have solved it. There were some erroneous links in the latex GUI.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal type `"which pdflatex"` and you should get something like /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex, depending on your system. If you get nothing you need to reinstall mactex. If you do get something say "%whatyougethere%", in Texmaker preferences on quickbuild (which is what I assume you are using change the command to

```
"%whatyougethere%" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

e.g.

```
"/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```